# Resume an open application on Android Wear

Tags: android-wear, google-keep

If I'm grocery shopping and have Google Keep up on my watch with the list, I'd ideally want the watch to go directly to the application every time I wake it until explicitly exiting. Under present behavior, it's necessary to navigate back to the application every time I want to look at another list item -- a step which makes its use utterly inconvenient.

Is this behavior configurable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered the PinAnApp app for android which provides a nifty swipe gesture to keep the current app open and/or the screen on. Fills the current hole until app vendors take advantage of the new Android Wear "always on" functionality directly. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.trigonesoft.pinanapp&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, watches tend to have a fairly low battery life. As a result, there are no settings that allow you to do an "always on" screen. The closest to what you may be looking for is Ambient Mode on the Moto360 - but even that turns off after about 15 seconds.

In later generations of the watch and Android Wear OS, I'm sure they'll begin implementing features that allow you to resume/pause apps and keep the screen on for longer periods of time.

Comment: I don't want the screen to stay on. I want the application to still be there when I reactivate it, instead of going back to the watch face and needing to navigate the menu again.

Comment: It's standard in Android Wear for apps to close when the screen turns off. That's just how the OS operates. You can verify this behavior with the built-in apps on the watch you're using. The only work-around solution for what you're looking for would involve keeping the screen on so the OS doesn't have the opportunity to close the app - which, again, isn't a current setting on any of the watches that I've used.